# How to update quantity when item is added to cart rather than add same item twice - Context API - Reaxt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management, react-state-management, react-context

I only have one item for my basket app, when I add it multiple times it adds multiple different basketItems all with same id and with same quantity so for example 3 items all of quantity 3. What I want however is for there just to be one item with a quantity of 3.

I also want to be able to remove the item from cart by quantity - so one at a time. however currently when I click to remove from cart it removes it entirely from cart even if quantity in cart is more than 1.

How do I do this?

code sandbox [here] (https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-jepsen-ix3dd?file=/src/pages/ProductDetailsPage.js&resolutionWidth=584&resolutionHeight=696)

code below:

CartReducer.js

```
import {ADD_TO_CART, CHANGE_CART_QUANTITY, DECREASE, REMOVE_FROM_CART} from '../Types'


export const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART: {
            return {
                ...state, 
                cart: [...state.cart, { ...action.payload, qty : 1}]
            };
        }
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter((c) => c.id !== action.payload.id,)

            };
        }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

CartContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { CartReducer } from "./CartReducer";
import { products } from "../../pages/ProductDetailsPage";

const Cart = createContext();


const Context = ({ children }) => {
 

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, {
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });

//   const [productState, productDispatch] = useReducer(productReducer, {
//     byStock: false,
//     byFastDelivery: false,
//     byRating: 0,
//     searchQuery: "",
//   });

//   console.log(productState);

  return (
    <Cart.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </Cart.Provider>
  );
};

export const CartState = () => {
  return useContext(Cart);
};

export default Context;
```

BasketItem.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import image from '../../assets/image.png'
// import { QuantityButtonDiv } from '../components/QuantityButtonDiv'
import plusButtonImage from '../../assets/vector+.png'
import subtractButtonImage from '../../assets/vector.png'
import { CartState } from '../../context/cart/CartContext'
import { ADD_TO_CART, DECREASE, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../../context/Types'
import CustomizedSelect from '../SelectInput'


export const BasketItem = ({item}) => {

    // const { cartItems, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext);
    const { 
        state: { cart },
        dispatch,
    } = CartState();

    return (
        <div   className="basket-item">
            <div className="title-div">
                <span>
                    {item.title}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={image}/>
            </div>
            <div className="price-div">
                <span>
                    £{item.price}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="basket-quantity-div">
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                        type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
                        payload: item,
                    })}  className="subtract-btn">
                    <img src={subtractButtonImage}/>
                </button>
                <span className="quantity-value">
                    {cart.length}
                </span>
                <button  onClick={() => dispatch({
                    type: ADD_TO_CART,
                    payload: item,
                })} className="add-btn">
                    <img src={plusButtonImage}/>
                </button>
            </div>  
            <div className="total-div">
                £{cart.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0)}
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react'
import image from '../../assets/image.png'

import { QuantityButtonDiv } from '../QuantityButtonDiv'
import {BasketItem} from '../basketItem/BasketItem'
import { CartContext, CartState } from '../../context/cart/CartContext'
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../../context/Types'

export const Product = ({product}) => {

    // const {addToCart, cartItems, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext)
    const { state: {cart}, dispatch } = CartState();

    const [stockCount, setStockCount] = useState(10)
    
   

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={image}/>
            </div>
            <div  className="details-div">
                <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                <span>
                    {product.description}
                </span>
                <span className="price">
                    £ {product.price}
                </span>
                <div className="stock-div">
                    {stockCount} in stock
                </div>
                <QuantityButtonDiv/>
                {cart.some((p) => p.id === product.id) ? (
                    //checking to see if item is in cart if so remove from cart button appears
                    <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                        type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
                        payload: product,
                    })}  className="remove-button">
                        Remove From Cart
                    </button>

                ) : (
                    <></>
                )}
                <button onClick={() => {dispatch({
                    type: ADD_TO_CART,
                    payload: product,
                }); setStockCount(stockCount-1)}} disable={stockCount <= 0}  className="add-to-cart-button">
                    {stockCount === 0 ? "Out Of Stock" : "Add To Cart"}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

before adding new product to cart, you need to check if the product is already in the cart. You need to check it in ADD_TO_CART case.
in REMOVE_FROM_CART case, check if the quantity is more than 1.
 If its more than 1, don't remove it.

Comment: Thanks for input will try this now, quick question though: you say check if quantity is more than one and if so don't remove it. However I want to be able to remove it if it is more than one but just remove it by quantities of 1?

Comment: It's your decision, you wrote that you want to delete one at a time, so maybe add an minus and plus buttons.

Comment: Do you have any code recommendations or examples for doing what you have recommended? I understand what I want to do and what you have suggested but translating it to code is hard